# Mystery exception thrown by code seemingly not even in my repository

Tags: php, symfony, command-line-interface

I have a PHP CLI application that throws an exception after 300s, it looks like this:

[image: weird exception]
Of course no documentation I could find would explain why, so I started digging myself by basically grepping around parts of the message. But nothing comes up!
For instance I would expect `grep -Ri ProcessTimedOutException .` run at the root of my repository to come up with something, but no...

[image: grep -Ri ProcessTimedOutException .]

I have also tried grepping other parts of the message to no avail...
I've even tried to grep things that are gitignored just in case grep started to take that into account but of course it does not.

Is there some unexisting code that somehow is able to run? I feel like I'm chasing a ghost. If anyone has a suggestion...

Comment: What does `examples/needelp` argument represent?

Comment: You are being led astray by something that is wrong with your grep.  Not sure what.  But if you look under vendor/symfony/process/Exception then you will find the ProcessTimedOutException class.  The exception itself is pretty clear.  You have something looping or waiting on another process and eventually timing out.

Comment: ls vendor/symfony : 
console  contracts  polyfill-ctype  polyfill-mbstring

Comment: I do not see how this is a duplicate as I'm not using a composer command